# Does Admob ask for location data?

Tags: android, admob

Does Admob ask for location data via the GPS? If my app doesn't need GPS but has Admob integrated, would the user need to authorise it for GPS access? Is GPS just optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AdMob SDK does **not** use GPS directly.  If your application already gets location information, you can supply it in the AdRequest object (`setLocation()` IIRC), but it is up to you to actually obtain the location information.

Comment: Also it's worth pointing out that using location for the sole purpose of providing it in ads is a violation of the TOS.

Comment: A violation of the TOS of AdMob or Android?

Comment: AdMob.  Also, it's worth pointing out that you supplying the location can be nice.  Imagine you were building a Maps application (like a restaurant review app).  You might want to show ads for the location the user is looking at instead of where they are.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have any GPS info that I could find in the management interface, and the one use of it that I configured does not send GPS info. It probably uses known ip/domain info to accumulate the GEO stats.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it is a good idea to start with the [documentation](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#targeting). You can specify the location, but it's optional. If you don't it uses (most probably) the IP address to determine rough location and target ads.

Answer (score 0):

It is optional.  Allowing access to location could improve ad targeting and revenues, 
but you will lose unlimited rating of your application, reducing it visibility on market.